# What is the correct implementation of a DoublyLinkedList class that extends LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have my own custom `LinkedList` class that has a pointer to the first `Node` in the list.  I now need to create a `DoublyLinkedList` class.  The only difference between the `DoublyLinkedList` and the `LinkedList` is that the `DoublyLinkedList` uses `DoubleNode`s instead of `Node`s.  My `DoubleNode` class extends the `Node` class.

What is the **correct** way create a `DoublyLinkedList` that extends `LinkedList`?

Would have have to constantly cast `DoubleNode`s to `Node`s?  Or is there a simpler way that I'm just missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [The `java.util.LinkedList` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) already implements a doubly-linked list. Why would you want to create your own? (Is this homework?)

Comment: You might consider not making DoublyLinkedList a subclass of LinkedList.  The operations in DoublyLinkedList have to do twice as much work as those in LinkedList, and as you noticed they act on DoubleNode's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to figure this out on my own.

As it turns out, the only method that needs to change for `DoublyLinkedList` is the `add` method.  Here's my `DoublyLinkedList` add method:

```
public void add(Object obj){
        DoubleNode newNode = new DoubleNode(obj);
        newNode.setPrev(getLast());
        super.add((Node)newNode);
    }
```

By creating a `new` DoubleNode and then casting it to a `Node`, I am able to keep most methods the same.  If I need to access the DoubleNode's `prev` pointer, I can downcast the Node as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) - having your node type as a parameterized type on your `LinkedList`.

Comment: But then `DoublyLinkedList` wouldn't extend `LinkedList`; or rather, `LinkedList<DoubleNode>` wouldn't be a subtype of `LinkedList<Node>`.

Comment: @ruakh - yes, another parent abstract class or interface would help here, otherwise any users of the LinkedList implementation would always have to declare it with the parameterized type (agreed, not ideal).

Comment: I don't see how that addresses my point. If `LinkedList` and `DoublyLinkedList` are subtypes of the same generic type, but with different type parameters (e.g., the former extends `AbstractLinkedList<Node>` and the latter extends `AbstractLinkedList<DoubleNode>`), then `DoublyLinkedList` cannot be a subtype of `LinkedList`.

Comment: LinkedList would have to accept the node type, not provide it - undesirably exposing the implementation details (the node type) as part of the API, unless additional interfaces / abstract classes were used.  For example, have a `BaseLinkedList` that accepts the types (and most of the `LinkedList` implementation), then a child `LinkedList` and `DoublyLinkedList` class that both extend `BaseLinkedList` with the appropriate node types.

Comment: Also, thinking about it -- even if we're O.K. with the linked-list and doubly-linked-list classes not having a supertype-subtype relationship, I'm not sure how much help generics would really be, in terms of implementing the classes. I mean, a doubly-linked-list isn't just a simply-linked-list of doubly-linking-nodes; it needs to maintain its `tail` field, and it needs to maintain its nodes' `previous` fields, and if the classes are to be properly encapsulated, then they need to provide iterators, and the one class's iterator will provide a method that the other's doesn't . . .

Comment: @ruakh - I completely agree, but I'm trying to answer the OP's question as asked.

Comment: So it sounds like `LinkedList` and `DoublyLinkedList` should both just implement a `List` interface and I should avoid making `DoublyLinkedList` a subclass of `LinkedList`...

Comment: @BoundinCode: I don't know about that. I mean, it seems like the only reason to have a separate `LinkedList` class and `DoublyLinkedList` class would be if `DoublyLinkedList` offered some functionality that `LinkedList` didn't; but if that's the case, then that functionality couldn't be in the `List` interface, anyway (because `LinkedList` wouldn't implement it). That said, you could have interfaces `LinkedList` and `DoublyLinkedList`, the latter extending the former, and have classes `LinkedListImpl` and `DoublyLinkedListImpl` to implement them, without one class extending the other.